# Received status code 409 from server: Conflict error while migrating spring boot app to Gradle 7.3.3

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I am moving my spring boot application from Gradle 5.3 to Gradle 7.3.3. I have mad the changes in the build.gradle accordingly as below:

It's just a snippet

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.7.RELEASE'
        set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR6")
        log4jVersion = '2.17.0'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.build.xxx.com"
            credentials {
                username = user
                password = pwd
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation(group: 'com.xxx.ym', name: 'external-service', version: '0.1.11', classifier: 'clientApi')
        implementation(group: 'com.xxx.ym', name: 'conformance-service', version: '1.0.2', classifier: 'clientApi')
        implementation(group: 'com.xxx.ym', name: 'security-service', version: '0.1.17', classifier: 'clientApi')
        implementation(group: 'com.xxx.ym', name: 'product-service', version: '1.2.0-9.0-development', classifier: 'clientApi')
        implementation(group: 'com.xxx.ym', name: 'service-client', version: '0.7.2')
        implementation(group: 'com.xxx.ym', name: 'reasons-service', version: '0.7.1')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    }
}
```

When I try to do a clean build using `gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies` I am always getting **Could not GET 'https://artifactory.build.ym.com/XXXX-SNAPSHOT/com/xxx/ym/external-service/0.1.11/external-service-0.1.11.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict** error for dependencies which are present in our own artifactory. With `Gradle 5.3` the build was succeeding without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm if you are observing a similar pattern of error in Artifactory as below while reproducing this issue (artifactory.log (or) artifactory-service.log)?

```
Sending HTTP error code 409: The repository 'REPOSITORY_NAME' rejected the resolution of an artifact 'REPOSITORY_NAME:FILE_PATH' due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy
```

If yes, then it appears to be the conflict between the request sent from the client and the type of request handled by the repository. Consider checking "Handle Releases" and "Handle Snapshots" checkboxes under the concerned Artifactory's respiratory settings. This should help to resolve this issue.